# How to create a temporary account for testnet with funds?

Tags: mist, wallets, ether, testnets, fees

I'm a newbie in using the ethereum wallet.

After I completely installed and downloaded data for the testnet I create a new account but my new account has nothing (0.00 Eth).

It lead to I can't do anything by this account. I try to create a new contract but it is hopeless (`the account you want to send from is empty`).

Please help me create a new account (temporary with a little Ether) for the testnet.

I'm using the *Etherum Wallet* and deploy the contract with the UI. Please, give me some instructions for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Creating An Account In Ethereum Wallet

Start up Ethereum Wallet. Make sure that you are on testnet by selecting the menu Develop -> Network -> Testnet(Morden).

On the main page, click on Add Account, and enter your password (and remember it).

## Getting Some Coins On Testnet

To get some coins to test with on testnet (from [Morden](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Morden)),

> #### Getting Ether
>
> One way to get Ether is by using the [Ethereum wei faucet](https://zerogox.com/ethereum/wei_faucet). Just type in your account address and enjoy some free ether.

Note that the site linked to above was not working @ 01/05/2016.

You can also get some ethers from [morden.ether.camp](https://morden.ether.camp/) or [test.ether.camp](https://test.ether.camp/) by clicking on the [Get Free Ethers] button on the top left of the page.
Note that these sites were not working @ 01/05/2016.

## Deploy A Contract

Please refer to [The Ethereum Wallet: An Introduction for Non-Devs](https://blog.slock.it/the-ethereum-wallet-an-introduction-for-non-devs-9c530f75c018) for a guide to deploying a contract on testnet.

## Additional Notes

There are not too many active peers on the Testnet network. Synchronising your blockchain is going to take a while, with periods when no synchronising occurs as connections to the few peers drop off with the following message:

```
I0501 19:08:26.403691   25657 downloader.go:267] Synchronisation failed: no peers to keep download active
```

Just be patient. And just shutdown and restart repeatedly to speed up this process.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 more testnets where you will probably want to test your contract:

`kovan` and `rinkeby` based on [Proof of Authority](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Proof-of-Authority-Chains)  consensus networks.

Kovan faucet methods: https://github.com/kovan-testnet/faucet

Rinkeby Github Authenticated faucet: https://faucet.rinkeby.io/

If you just want to test your code, I'd highly recommend you to use [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) which is basically a private ethereum chain, which is much faster approach and no need to syncronize full blockchain. 
There is also a project going on(alpha) to visualize testrpc - https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache - webUI for testrpc

Answer (score 2):

This site is working as of 03/02/2017

http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/

It's a free faucet...

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'Develop' menu item in the Wallet. Under it there is a Network option where you can select Test Network.

Also under the Develop menu, there is a Start Mining (Test Only) option. If you select it, you might make some Ether.

Update: I turned on the Start Mining (Test Only) in my Ethereum Wallet. After a few hours, I had 5 ethers in my account (Test network).

Answer (score 0):

As of 7th August 2017, the EthTools.com [Ropsten Faucet](https://ethtools.com/ropsten/tools/faucet/) is now live.

You can get up to 5 Ether send to your address on the Ropsten test network every 24 hours.

There is also a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoxxZD9afpk) outlining exactly how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Worked like a charm using this https://ethtools.com/ropsten/tools/faucet/