# How to track mining progress on Testnet?

Tags: mining, testnets

<sup>(beginner question)</sup>

I have installed Ethereum Wallet 0.7.6 on Windows. It shows 5-6 peers and 1,230,865 (growing every ~1 minute). Two days ago I clicked on "Start Mining" and the wallet has been running continuously for over 48 hours now. I have 0 ether balance, but according to [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4069/3099), however, I *should have some Testnet ethers within 20 minutes, mining using the CPU only*.

Update: I found an external configuration reason for the lack of results and indeed the client wasn't mining, but still my question is valid:

How can I track my mining activities on Testnet (shall I use the same tools as for Main Network)?

What can I do when my balance is stuck at zero? Shall I check some website (explorer)? Look at the logs? Check something in the wallet interface?

---

Advised to check the Etherscan explorer I would like to stress I am talking about a situation where I have not mined any block for 48 hours and it shows like this:

[image: Etherscan results]

From the screen above (or subsequent links) I cannot see a way to tell if my Mist is actually mining something or not.

As a contrary, if I ran `geth` on Main Network in CLI, I could see things being processed even if I didn't get any results (blocks).

Answer (score 3):

Ethereum Wallet keeps a log of your mining activity and it is more or less real time. In my case, I have the Mac Ethereum Wallet app and if I click on **Develop** > **Show Log File**, the app takes me to the location of the log-files. On Mac, you can open the most recent log-file with Console and then you see your progress. If you are mining actively, you should see something like:

```
I0208 10:27:55.933072 core/blockchain.go:1070] imported 1 blocks, 0 txs (0.000 Mg) in 10.527ms (0.000 Mg/s). #495315 [94c82d0c…]
I0208 10:27:55.942106 miner/worker.go:514] commit new work on block 495316 with 4 txs & 0 uncles. Took 8.921554ms
```

Since I also haven't gotten any Ether for mining yet, I cannot tell you how a successful block commit and Ether transaction would look like. But at least you can see whether you are actually mining or not.

Comment: Some more information here: [Ethereum Forum](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/2619/miner-committing-new-work-but-havent-seen-mined-block-yet)

Answer (score 2):

You can track block mined by your account on any testnet explorer. E.g. http://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0x8d80fe3a57f2f48bff06db68f3d2c94ea23c88c7#mine.

Testnet is the same technology, but different configuration (e.g. different network number from main network). So the explorer are able to track testnet and main network side-by-side with minimal additional cost.

Comment: (1) So there is no difference between Testnet and Main Network? I should use the same tools, the same ...scope? By coincidence 10 minutes ago I mined 5.0378258 ether and one block lists, but (2) Where in the explorer could I see the progress during those 48 hours when I indeed had zero balance? -- And this (2) was my real question, I did not want to see mined blocks because I had none. I wanted to confirm that I am on a right path to getting one.

Comment: Ad. (1) I see, it's the subdomain that determines the scope.

Comment: And that was my question, so you should add it to answer, please. But I can't see how it allows me to see actual progress towards the first mined block.

Comment: You cannot track because there is no progress. Mining is pure probability and luck.

Comment: "*You cannot track because...*" - I don't know that, hence my question (i.e. your remark again should be a part of the answer). However, if I ran `geth` on Main Network in CLI, I could see things being processed even if I didn't have any results, with Ethereum Wallet I see nothing.