# Unable to receive ether in testnet account

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, ether, testnets, faucets

I have set up a test net account using the ethereum wallet on my PC. I have left my miner on in the test environment for several hours and failed to mine test ether. I have also tried getting ether from https://zerogox.com/ethereum/wei_faucet but the it says it is unable to send me ether. The testnet blockchain seems to have synced fine. Can someone help please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a temporary account for testnet with funds?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/how-to-create-a-temporary-account-for-testnet-with-funds)

Comment: Is your question about testnet faucets or the specific mining issue? Could you clarify what you need most right now?